# Bash completion: Allow flags once

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I have a basic complete function:

```
_my_complete () 
{ 
    local cur prev opts opts2;
    COMPREPLY=();
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}";
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}";
    opts="foo bar";
    opts2="-f -s";
    case ${COMP_CWORD} in 
        1)
            COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}))
        ;;
        2 | 4)
            COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${opts2}" -- ${cur}))
        ;;
    esac
}
```

How can limit the completion to accept the -f or the -s only once in the command line?

Thanks

Comment: As you know all the arguments are in `${COMP_WORDS[@]}` so you can simply check if `-f` or `-s` is already in the array.

Comment: Yes, but how and where do I check for it and edit the `opts2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Inspired by comment of @whjm and this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104837/intersection-of-two-arrays-in-bash)

```
_my_complete() {
        local cur prev opts opts2 subopts ;
        COMPREPLY=();
        cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}";
        prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}";
        opts="foo bar";
        opts2="-f -s";
        subopts=();

        for i in ${opts2}
        do
                for j in "${COMP_WORDS[@]}"
                do
                        if [[ "$i" == "$j" ]] 
                        then
                                continue 2
                        fi
                done
                subopts+=("$i")
        done  

        case ${COMP_CWORD} in
            1)
                    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}))
                    ;;
            2|4)
                    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${subopts[*]}" -- ${cur}))
                    ;;
        esac
}
```

Comment: There's easier way to get `cur` and `prev`. Just write `cur=$2` and `prev=$3`. And `$1` is the command itself.

Comment: The complex way was suggested by several sites' examples. So I stuck with that.

Comment: `$1..3` always works fine for me. If you are very clear about the difference with `${COMP_WORDS[@]}` then you know exactly when to use which. For me, *good enough* is enough. :)